# CurrencyWidget app run time errors

Tags: java, android, logcat, runtimeexception

I am new to android programming, just got the code from http://www.droiddraw.org/tut4.html and trying to make a currency converter application. I am planning to get the currency conversion rates from the Internet and using JSON in the app. The problem is that  I cannot run the applications and I have tried every possible thing and solutions available on the Internet to solve this issue e.g. clean project, build, refresh, re-importing, etc . Please help me and point out that where I am missing anything which is causing Fatal Exception and the app displays that "CurrencyWidget has stopped unexpectedly ". 
I am attaching my full project code and LogCat errors here, please help me.

```
CurrencyWidget.java

package com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class CurrencyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // To prevent any ANR timeouts, we perform the update in a service
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    }

    public static double getRate() {
        // In a real app, you might want to cache this object for performance.
        HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // In reality this would be a dynamic service.
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=");

        double rate = 0.00;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(get);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
            outstream.flush();
            outstream.close();
            String data = new String(outstream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(data));
            rate = obj.getDouble("rate");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("CurrencyWidget", "IO Error", ex);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.e("CurrencyWidget", "Parse error", ex);
        }
        return rate;
    }

    /**
     * Reads the current rate from droiddraw.org.
     */
    public static class UpdateService extends Service {
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // Build the widget update for today
            RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this, getRate());

            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, CurrencyWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }

        public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context, double rate) {
            // Build an update that holds the updated widget contents
            RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            // Build the text for the widget
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
            String euroToDollar = format.format(rate);
            String dollarToEuro = format.format(1 / rate);
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.etod, "Euros to Dollars: " + euroToDollar);
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.dtoe, "Dollars to Euros: " + dollarToEuro);

            // Set up the button click handler
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launchIntent.setClass(context, CurrencyWidget.class);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,   
                    launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.converter, pendingIntent);

            return updateViews; 
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".CurrencyWidget" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <!-- Service to perform web API queries -->
        <service android:name=".CurrencyWidget$UpdateService" />

        <receiver
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".CurrencyWidget" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_description" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>



res/layout/widget.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/appwidget_bg" >
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/converter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Converter" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dtoe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="&quot;&quot;" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etod "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Loading" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>

/res/xml/widget_description.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="60000"
    />

LogCat Error

11-25 03:35:06.923: D/AndroidRuntime(351): Shutting down VM
11-25 03:35:06.923: W/dalvikvm(351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget/com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget.CurrencyWidget}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget.CurrencyWidget
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kwantlen.android.currencywidget.CurrencyWidget
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
11-25 03:35:06.962: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`CurrencyWidget` is an `AppWidgetProvider`, not an `Activity`. You are creating a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` to try to start up `CurrencyWidget` as an `Activity`. This will not work.